# MS Teams: Add-on for guys to flag their capacity for extra work? (see mockup image)

Tags: office365, ms-office, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, teams-toolkit

I'm new to a company and my manager wants me to overhaul our portfolios Teams channels. It's currently unused except for chat and scheduling meetings.

One tab/add-on I'd like to implement is something that allows each team member to publicly state their capacity to take on extra work (we're calling this a "bandwith meter")

Ideally it would look something like this:
[image: ideal interface for bandwith meter]

Each user just sets their bandwith/free time to take on extra work on a scale of totally free, to absolutely not free.

Managers are then able to see at a glance who they can ask to take on extra tasks.

Does an add-on like this exist?

A workaround would be to use an Excel sheet tab with a row for each colleague, where they change their corresponding value in the "Bandwith" tab between 0 and 10, but that would look kind of crap and I know nobody would use it. A nifty slider with their user photograph would be so much slicker.

Any products out there??

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following resources

1. [Microsoft Teams tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs) to create tabs.
2. [Slider](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.57.0/components/slider/definition) in Fluent UI to create slider.
3. [Person component in the Microsoft Graph Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/person) to get the profile picture.